# Consider only 2 decimal places

Tags: python

How do I instruct python that it should consider only 2 decimal spaces?

```
x = -1.7999999999999998 +  0.20000000000000018 +  0.20000000000000018  - 0.7999999999999998 + 2.2
print('%.02f' % x)
```

> 0.00

I have manually adjusted values as below. But is there any way to automate this?

```
y = -1.79 + 0.20 + 0.20 - 0.79 + 2.2
print('%.02f' % y)
```

---

Update: I am trying to calculate sum of mean differences. I am not getting expected values.

```
y = [1,3,3,2,5]

avg = sum(y) / len(y)

mylist = list()
for i in y:
    mylist.append(i - avg)

sum(mylist)
```

Comment: without having the numbers in variables?

Comment: That question will explain the concept at higher level. But it does not answer the question of how to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```py
"{0:.2f}".format(x)
```

Or

```py
round(x, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all of the context, but I wouldn't opt for anything fancy:

```
x = -1.7999999999999998 +  0.20000000000000018 +  0.20000000000000018  - 0.7999999999999998 + 2.2
x = round(x, 2)
print(x)
```

This should work fine.